# React method return value won't show in render()

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I was playing around in React, and I was trying to have a method return a value, which I would then use to display in the render() method, however when I try to nothing is displayed.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.DisplayTest = this.DisplayTest.bind(this);
  }
  DisplayTest() {
    return <h1>Test</h1>;
  }
  render() {
    return <div>{this.DisplayTest}</div>;
  }
}
export default Test;
```

Comment: You need to call the method as  ```{this.DisplayTest()}```

Answer (score 1):

DisplayTest is a method therefore in order to return a value, you will have to execute it.

```
  render() {
    return <div>{this.DisplayTest()}</div>;
  }
```

Another way is to make use of class getter

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

So, you will have to declare a getter method like

```
 get DisplayTest() {
    return <h1>Test</h1>;
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.DisplayTest}</div>;
  }
```

And then, your current implementation will work.

Answer (score 0):

Please add following { this.DisplayTest() }